# Control wsgiref simple_server log

Tags: python, python-2.7, wsgiref

I'm playing with `wsgiref.simple_server` to study the world of web servers.

I would like to control the log generated, but could not find anything about it in [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wsgiref.html).

My code looks like this:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

def application(environ, start_response):
  start_response('200 OK', headers)
  return ['Hello World']

httpd = make_server('', 8000, application)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`wsgiref.simple_server.make_server` by default creates a `WSGIServer` with `WSGIRequestHandler`:

```
def make_server(
    host, port, app, server_class=WSGIServer, handler_class=WSGIRequestHandler):
    """Create a new WSGI server listening on `host` and `port` for `app`"""
    server = server_class((host, port), handler_class)
    server.set_app(app)
    return server
```

`WSGIRequestHandler` here extends from `BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler`, where the logging magic turns out to be:

```
def log_message(self, format, *args):
    sys.stderr.write("%s - - [%s] %s\n" %
                     (self.client_address[0],
                      self.log_date_time_string(),
                      format%args))
```

So it's logging to stderr, actually, not to python logging module. You can override this in your own handler:

```
class NoLoggingWSGIRequestHandler(WSGIRequestHandler):

    def log_message(self, format, *args):
        pass
```

And pass your custom handler to the server instead:

```
httpd = make_server('', 8000, application, handler_class=NoLoggingWSGIRequestHandler)
```

Comment: `WSGIRequestHandler` is accessible via `from wsgiref.simple_server import WSGIRequestHandler`.

Comment: You may need to override `log` instead of `log_message`

Answer (score -1):

Another weird trick, is to use `redirect_stderr`.

```
import os
from contextlib import redirect_stderr


with redirect_stderr(open(os.devnull, "w")):
    with make_server("", 8051, app) as httpd:
        httpd.handle_request()
```